# Camera moves around by itself in Unity 3D when using Xbox 360 Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox360

I'm using my Xbox 360 controller in Unity 3D. When I'm debugging the camera is moving around by itself, with no input from the controller. Is this meant to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the "Dead" setting to 0.1 in the Input settings. And also the sensitivity to 0.3, although this wasn't needed, just added a bit of speed to rotating.

Comment: I wanted to say that. Typically if the controller has been in use the thumbsticks don't center precisely. This is not usually noticable in games because they use an appropriate deadzone.

Comment: I thought it may be down to the controller to be honest. I messed about with the deadzone and it worked fine.